# Shell Script: Variable assinment working in strange way

Tags: bash, shell

Below is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FA_log_locations=`echo $1| sed 's/,/" "/g; s/$/")/g; s/^/("/g'`
echo $FA_log_locations
for jj in FA
do

        PASSWORD=$FA_PASSWORD
        USER=$FA_USER

        eval number_of_dirs=\${#${jj}_log_locations[@]}
        for ii in `seq 0 $((number_of_dirs-1))`
        do
                eval new_dirname=${jj}_type_${ii}
                eval source_details=\${HOST_$jj}
                eval source_loc=\${${jj}_log_locations[\$ii]}
                export ${jj}_type_${ii}="${source_loc}"
                echo $ii
        done
done
```

When I am running into debug mode, below is the output

```
# bash -x /tmp/test.sh /u01,/u02
++ echo /u01,/u02
++ sed 's/,/" "/g; s/$/")/g; s/^/("/g'
+ FA_log_locations='("/u01" "/u02")'
+ echo '("/u01"' '"/u02")'
("/u01" "/u02")
+ for jj in FA
+ PASSWORD=
+ USER=
+ eval 'number_of_dirs=${#FA_log_locations[@]}'
++ number_of_dirs=1
++ seq 0 0
+ for ii in '`seq 0 $((number_of_dirs-1))`'
+ eval new_dirname=FA_type_0
++ new_dirname=FA_type_0
+ eval 'source_details=${HOST_FA}'
++ source_details=
+ eval 'source_loc=${FA_log_locations[$ii]}'
++ source_loc='("/u01" "/u02")'
+ export 'FA_type_0=("/u01" "/u02")'
+ FA_type_0='("/u01" "/u02")'
+ echo 0
0
```

Now my questions are:

1. Why it is counting directory 1 instead of 2.?
2. Why is there an extra "'" in FA_log_locations='("/u01" "/u02")' ?

Comment: For the 1st point, you can see that in debug mode that `FA_log_locations` is not an array but a string. So its size will be 1. The extra quote is caused by bash expansion. You need to write the attribution as an array, like so : `FA_log_locations=( $(echo $1| sed 's/,/" "/g; s/$/")/g; s/^/("/g'))`

Comment: For the 2nd point, it's just the output of `set -x`, the variable itself doesn't contain single quotes.

Comment: And now you see why you should ask two questions as two separate posts.

Comment: @Aserre When i ran your code, its giving FA_type_0='("/u01"' instead of FA_type_0=/u01, which is not correct.
Thanks Choroba for 2nd point.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly intended. This is caused by you sed command `s/$/")/g; s/^/("/g`. You could probably replace your `sed` command by `sed 's/,/ /g`. To be honest, your code could be optimised greatly by using the variable `$@` instead of the `FA_log_locations` (and passing the arguments as separate arguments, not separated by commas)